# Django site, getting error __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' when calling a view

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the error message above when trying to load my edit_transaction view.  I know what the error means but don't understand why it is happening as it was working before and still works on another similar page.  Can provide more code if needed, I'm wondering though if there is something blindingly obvious here, so much so that I can't see it.

Full traceback:

> Traceback:
>
> File "/Users/c/.virtualenvs/django-budget/lib/python3.5/site->packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>    42.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/Users/c/.virtualenvs/django-budget/lib/python3.5/site->packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>    187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/Users/c/.virtualenvs/django-budget/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/c/.virtualenvs/django-budget/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/c/sites/budget/budget/views.py" in edit_transaction
>     83.         form = TransactionForm(instance=transaction)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /budget/transaction/3/edit/
>   Exception Value: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

extract from urls.py:

```
url(r'^transaction/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.edit_transaction, name='edit_transaction'),
```

extract from views.py:

```
@login_required
def edit_transaction(request, pk):
    transaction = get_object_or_404(Transaction, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST, instance=transaction)
        if form.is_valid():
            transaction = form.save(commit=False)
            transaction.updated = timezone.now()
            transaction.save()
            return redirect('view_transaction_detail', pk=transaction.pk)
    else:
        form = TransactionForm(instance=transaction)
    return render(request, 'budget/new_transaction.html', {'form': form})
```

template extract:

```
{% extends 'budget/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>{{ transaction.title }}</h2>
    <h4>{{ transaction.date }}</h4>
    <h4>Transaction type: {{ transaction.transaction_type }}</h4>
    <h4>Category: {{ transaction.category }}</h4>
    <h4>Budgeted amount: {{ transaction.budgeted_amount }}</h4>
    <h4>Actual amount: {{ transaction.actual_amount }}</h4>
    <h4>Difference: {{ difference }}</h4>
    <h4>Comments: {{ transaction.comments }}</h4>

    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'edit_transaction' pk=transaction.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'delete_transaction' pk=transaction.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <h5><a href="{% url 'summary' %}">Back to summary</a></h5>

{% endblock %}
```

**Edited to add TranscationForm code**

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('title', 'transaction_type', 'category', 'budgeted_amount', 'actual_amount', 'date', 'comments',)

    #new_category field to allow you to add a new category
    new_category = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label="New Category Title")

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #category is now not a required field because you will use category OR new_category
        self.fields['category'].required=False
        #set to allow use of self.request.user to set user for category
        self.request = request

    def clean(self):
        category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')
        new_category = self.cleaned_data.get('new_category')
        if not category and not new_category:
            # raise an error if neither a category is selected nor a new category is entered
            raise forms.ValidationError('Category or New category field is required')
        elif not category:
            # create category from new_category
            category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(title=new_category, defaults={'user': self.request.user})
            self.cleaned_data['category'] = category

        return super(TransactionForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: Can you show the code for TransactionForm?

Comment: edited to add code as requested

Comment: As that code shows, you've modified the signature of the form to require a `request` argument. Hi need Ruby provide that argument, both times you instantiate the form in your view.

Comment: Thank you this is really obvious now that you've pointed it out. Couldn't see the wood for the trees...

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you should write:

```
form = TransactionForm(request=request, instance=transaction)
```

instead of :

```
form = TransactionForm(request.POST, instance=transaction)
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed `form = TransactionForm(instance=transaction)` to `form = TransactionForm(request=request, instance=transaction)` and the view now loads correctly, but there's now another issue in that the form does not save any changes made.

Comment: do you check if it reaches where you are going to save to form?!

Comment: in other words is your form returning any errors in validation stage?!